# Filter on column to pull out specific words

Tags: excel, vba

The code below sets up a filter on column E to pull out specific numbers.

I want my function to do the same thing in column K but with specific words.

I've attempted to change `.Value2` to `.Value` and even `.text` thinking it was a problem with the way the code was reading the info.

```vb
Sub IMChangeNotice()
Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, lr As Long
Dim CNMaster As Worksheet

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set CNMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

On Error Resume Next

'Setup RD
    Range("E:E").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("E2:E" & lrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[1],2)"

'Filter RD's and remove non Hardgoods
    Range("A1:O" & lrow).AutoFilter
    
    Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With CNMaster
     lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lr
         Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, "E").Value2)
             Case "56", "57", "60", "67", "70", "71", "72", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85"
                 'do nothing
             Case Else
                 arr.Item(CStr(.Cells(i, "E").Value2)) = vbNullString
         End Select
     Next i
     .Range("A1:O" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=arr.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
     .Cells(1, 5).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    CNMaster.ShowAllData
Set arr = Nothing

ChangeType

End Sub
```

```
Function ChangeType()
Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, lr As Long
Dim CNMaster As Worksheet

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set CNMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Filter Change type and remove unneeded changes
    Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With CNMaster
     lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lr
         Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, "L").Value2)
             Case "Article Name", "Direct Import", "Excess No Reorder", "RD", "SFC", "Vendor Item", "Vendor Name"
                 'do nothing
             Case Else
                 arr.Item(CStr(.Cells(i, "L").Value2)) = vbNullString
         End Select
     Next i
     .Range("A1:O" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=arr.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
     .Cells(1, 12).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

CNMaster.ShowAllData

End Function
```

Comment: why is it a function?  Functions return something.  It should probably be a sub. Not your problem just a note.

Comment: I was just trying to separate the processes out  so they are easier to see and show that they are almost exactly the same. I can change to a sub but get the same issue. also helps me troubleshoot as I test since I can just run that portion of the code.

Comment: You're comparing the cell values **in upper case** to a list of values not in upper case, so...

Comment: Doh! that makes sense! I figured it out. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed line `Select Case UCase(.Cells(i, "L").Value2)` to `Select Case .Cells(i, "L").Value2` in order to remove case sensitive issue

```
Function ChangeType()
Dim lrow As Long, i As Long, lr As Long
Dim CNMaster As Worksheet

lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set CNMaster = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

'Filter Change type and remove unneeded changes
    Set arr = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    With CNMaster
     lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lr
         Select Case .Cells(i, "L").Value2
             Case "Article Name", "Direct Import", "Excess No Reorder", "RD", "SFC", "Vendor Item", "Vendor Name"
                 'do nothing
             Case Else
                 arr.Item(CStr(.Cells(i, "L").Value2)) = vbNullString
         End Select
     Next i
     .Range("A1:O" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=arr.keys, Operator:=xlFilterValues
     .Cells(1, 12).Offset(1, 0).Resize(lrow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

CNMaster.ShowAllData

End Function
```